# Check which beans have loaded in spring context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a series of odd errors in testing and deployment.  They seem to indicate that some of my beans are not loading into the context, despite them being defined in applicationContext.xml.

Is there any way to check during testing which beans have actually been loaded?  Or to find a complete list of beans loaded at run time?

Thanks,
b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At startup, Spring logs at info level the names of all the beans being loaded by a context. Or in code, you can use [`getBeanDefinitionNames()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames%28%29) to get all the bean names.

Comment: I suspected it would be easy, off to give this a try and THANKS!

Comment: This was useful i a test for those who need it:     '@'Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    '@'Test
    public void testContext() {
        String[] beans = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String b : beans) {
            System.out.println(" *** " + b);
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

if there is more than one context say if you are using spring mvc you can use something more powerful like this.

```
public class SampleContextApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationContextEvent> {

    private Map<String,ApplicationContext> contextMap = new Hashtable<String,ApplicationContext>();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextEvent event) {
        if( event instanceof ContextStartedEvent || event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent){
            this.getContextMap().put(event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName(), event.getApplicationContext());
        }

    }

    public Map<String,ApplicationContext> getContextMap() {
        return contextMap;
    }   
}
```

You can then inject the listener where it is needed, and extract the map of contextens and then interogate it for all its bean, using the `getBeanDefinitionNames()`

```
@Autowired
private StatusTestsApplicationListener listener;
```

Comment: Thanks @ams I'm not sure how to use this yet.